# How to add "read more" link with many paragraphs in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a content `DIV` with many paragraphs.
This is how its' markup look,

```
<div class="more">
    <p>Based on a study of its skull, scientists say that an extinct one-tonne relative of the guinea pig probably used its 30cm incisors like tusks. Based on a study of its skull, scientists say that an extinct one-tonne relative of the guinea pig probably used its 30cm incisors like tusks. </p>
    <p>That an extinct one-tonne relative of the ncisors like tusks. Based on a study of its skull, scientists say that an extinct one-tonne relative of the guinea pig probably used its 30cm incisors like tusks. </p>
    <p>Extinct one-tonne relative of the guinea pig probably used its 30cm incisors like tusks. Based on a study of its skull, scientists say that an extinct one-tonne relative of the guinea pig probably used its 30cm incisors like tusks. </p>
</div>
```

Now I need to add a link to "read more" once the characters reach to 300 of  `<div class="more">`. And also I would like to display this link  as a toggle.

Just I tried it with jquery, but I couldn't figure it out properly.

This is my jquery -

```
var showChar = 300;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "more";
var lesstext = "less";
$('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3e3jv0kn/1/) with current jquery

Hope somebody may help me out. Thank you.

Comment: you can check this out  http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this will help keep `<p>` and have 300 chars count.

```js
var showChar = 300;
 var ellipsestext = "...";
 var moretext = "more";
 var lesstext = "less";
 $('.more').each(function() {
   var content = $(this).html();
   var textcontent = $(this).text();

   if (textcontent.length > showChar) {

     var c = textcontent.substr(0, showChar);
     //var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

     var html = '<span class="container"><span>' + c + '</span>' + '<span class="moreelipses">' + ellipsestext + '</span></span><span class="morecontent">' + content + '</span>';

     $(this).html(html);
        $(this).after('<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a>');
   }

 });

 $(".morelink").click(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
     $(this).removeClass("less");
     $(this).html(moretext);
        $(this).prev().children('.morecontent').fadeToggle(500, function(){
          $(this).prev().fadeToggle(500);
        });
       
   } else {
     $(this).addClass("less");
     $(this).html(lesstext);
        $(this).prev().children('.container').fadeToggle(500, function(){
          $(this).next().fadeToggle(500);
        });
   }
      //$(this).prev().children().fadeToggle();
   //$(this).parent().prev().prev().fadeToggle(500);
   //$(this).parent().prev().delay(600).fadeToggle(500);
   
   return false;
 });
```

```css
.morecontent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="more">
  <p>Based on a study of its skull, scientists say that an extinct one-tonne relative of the guinea pig probably used its 30cm incisors like tusks. Based on a study of its skull, scientists say that an extinct one-tonne relative of the guins 30cm incisors
    like tusks.</p>
  <p>That an extinct one-tonne relative of the ncisors like tusks. Based on a study of its skull, scientists say that an extinct one-tonne relative guinea picm incisors like tusks.</p>
  <p>Extinct one-tonne relative of the guinea pig probably used its 30cm incisors like tusks. Based on a study of its skull, scientists say that an extinct one-tonne relative of the guinea pig probably used its 30cm incisors like tusks.</p>
</div>
```

Edit: Snippet updated - Added Fade effects with `<a href="morelink">` outside container

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But two things just I need to know, Is there any way to add `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` with this? And also how I display`<a href="morelink">` from outside of my content DIV?

Comment: Geat.. Thanks again. One thing How I change this code if `<a href="morelink">` wrap in a div. Eg. `<div class="readmore"><a href="" class="morelink">Read More</a> </div>`

Comment: I tried it with `find()` and `prev().prev()`. But I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Prachit - Won't this solution fall apart if the first paragraph is smaller than 300 chars?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can acheive [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/3e3jv0kn/11/)

```
var content = $(this).text();
//var content = $(this).html();
```

if the browser found any html tag break then its automatically enclosed with the related tag: `</p>`.

Comment: @TNK reading content lenght is not the good solution if you want the HTML tags remaining, Does height works for your solution like in this plugin? http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/

Answer (score 0):

May be below code snippet will help you :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 


           var showChar = 300;
           var ellipsestext = "...";
           var moretext = "more";
           var lesstext = "less";
           var h = "";
           var content = $(".more").text();

           if(content.length > showChar) 
           {
                var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
                h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

                var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span>&nbsp;<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></span>';

                $(".more").html(html);
                $('.morecontent').hide();
            }

        $(".morelink").click(function()
        {
            if($(this).hasClass("less")) 
            {
                $('.more').remove(h);
                $(this).removeClass("less");
                $(this).html(moretext);
            } 
            else 
            {
                $('.more').append(h);
                $(this).addClass("less");
                $(this).html(lesstext);
            }

            $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
            $(this).prev().toggle();
            return false;
        });

});
```

Comment: Have you tested this script in jsfiddle?

Comment: @jogesh_pi : on my local machine have tested it.

Comment: create a fiddle and test it or edit the fiddle of user, seems your code breaks.